# Implement an Event Manager with multi methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

Implement an EventManager class

1. push(event: string, method: Function)
2. remove(event: string, method: Function)
3. print(event: string, data: somedata)

```
const channel = new EventManager;

const cb1 = data => console.log('Cb 1:', data);
const cb2 = data => console.log('Cb 2:', data);
const cb3 = data => console.log('Cb 3:', data);

channel.push('ERROR', cb1);
channel.push('ERROR', cb2);
channel.push('SUCCESS', cb3);

channel.print('ERROR', { foo: 'bar' });
channel.print('SUCCESS', { food: 'apple' });
// Cb 1: { foo: 'bar' }
// Cb 2: { foo: 'bar' }
// Cb 3: { food: 'apple' }

channel.remove('ERROR', cb1);
channel.print('ERROR', { bat: 'batt' });
// Cb 2: { bat: 'batt' }
```

My idea is using new Map() to fix the dead-end loop issue, map's
key is event type, the value is list of function

1. push - add the function into the list
2. remove - remove the function from the list
3. print - use event type get the list from the map, data call the function

```
var list = [];
var map = {}
function push(type, func) {
    list.add(func);
    map.set(type, list);
}
function remove(type, func) {
    list.remove(func);
    map.set(type, list);
}
```

I don't know how to implement "print" method, and I am not sure about do I need to use some callback for this problem? 
Also not sure my "push" and "remove" are on the right track

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close (not really)

```js
class EventManager {
    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }
    subscribe(event, callback) {
        const map = this.events[event] = this.events[event] || new Map;
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            map.set(callback);
        }
    }
    publish(event, data) {
        const map = this.events[event];
        if (map) {
            [...map].forEach(([cb]) => cb(data));
        }        
    }
    unsubscribe(event, callback) {
        const map = this.events[event];
        if (map) {
            map.delete(callback);
        }
    }
}
channel = new EventManager;
const callback1 = data => console.log('Callback 1:', data);
const callback2 = data => console.log('Callback 2:', data);
const callback3 = data => console.log('Callback 3:', data);

channel.subscribe('request.error', callback1);
channel.subscribe('request.error', callback2);
channel.subscribe('request.success', callback3);

channel.publish('request.error', { foo: 'bar' });
channel.publish('request.success', { lorem: 'ipsum' });

// Expected output in console:
//
// Callback 1: { foo: 'bar' }
// Callback 2: { foo: 'bar' }
// Callback 3: { lorem: 'ipsum' }

channel.unsubscribe('request.error', callback1);
channel.publish('request.error', { bar: 'baz' });

// Expected output in console:
//
// Callback 2: { bar: 'baz' }
```

Comment: Btw, still got a question that this "[...map].forEach(([cb]) => cb(data));" Would you mind to explain this part? So in the publish function, we just need to get all of the element in map and find the one we need? Is that right?

Comment: `[...map]` more or less "turns" a map into an iterable so you can use forEach :p

Comment: Another question, why we need to put cb into an array [cb]? and I tried if I removed "[]" it will give me error said:  "cb is not a function" but I still don't understand the root cause.

Comment: `console.log([...map])` in the publsh function to see why

Comment: Okay, I see the reason. Looks like we can just use Set, instead of Map right? Since you use an object to like {event : Map<callBack>}, but we never touched the value of the map, we just use the key. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, not sure why I was using map - I think I've over complicated the answer to be fair :p - Oh, I know why ... it makes `unsubscribe` easier, rather than finding the callback in an array and splicing the array, just a simple `map.delete`